# ActionBar covering my activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview, material-design

I have an activity whose xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ivykoko.com.likechecker.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And it looks like this: [image]

As you can see, the action bar is covering the top of the recyclerview. What can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does this surprise you?

Comment: @tim-castelijns Well, I'm a begginer to android and don't know what to do :S

Comment: Let's start by telling us what you expected to see, and why

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: @howdoidothis I want the action bar not to cover the first element of the recyclerview

Comment: oh, just put it inside the content_main.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add what you have changed and why

Comment: So, do I have to replace my CoordinatorLayout for a LinearLayout? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just put my code into your cordiantor layout. This happened because you put a recycler view in the screen with match parent params, and after that you put a toolbar aswell, without any location, so both component align on the top of parent, and toolbar cover the recyclerview.

Comment: In most cases `CoordinatorLayout` cannot be replaced with `LinearLayout` as there is a `FloatingActionButton` on screen too. correct answer is given by Mahendra and SpaceBison below

Answer (score 5):

Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your RecyclerView. This will cause the CoordinatorLayout to position it below the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Put Appbar as direct first child of coordinator layout and use `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in RecyclerView.