# Why is the Action bar covering my listView?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm following the steps outlined at `https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html` to add an action bar to my activity.

However, adding it as described covers my ListView. The list has 2 entries. Before I tried to add the Action Bar, this is what it looked like:

[image]

Here I followed the steps and adjusted the manifest and my activity layout:

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: Activity screenshot]

I tried wrapping the Toolbar with an AppBarLayout object as shown at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845629/actionbar-covering-my-activity`, but that didn't work.

How do I add an ActionBar to my activity and not cover the ListView. I would like to add a couple of buttons to the activity's action bar (not the overflow menu) so I can give options for adding to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to add android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" in listview as your layout is relative.